# How to get json as a string from a url?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to have an array with the value of json:

```
arr[ ] array = {"http://www.ip-api.com/json"};
```

when I print this array, how can I have json but not "http://www.ip-api.com/json" as a string?

Comment: You have to call the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSON generating library such as Jackson and have it serialize the data structure.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

If you want to actually mean that you want to call the service at that URL then you need to use a suitable library for that...